# What is this technique called in Java?

Tags: java, anonymous-class

I'm a C++ programmer, and I was reading this [site](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/j-mocktest.html) when I came across the example below. What is this technique called in Java? How is it useful?

```
class Application {
...
  public void run() {
    View v = createView();
    v.display();
...
  protected View createView() {
    return new View();
  }
...
}    

class ApplicationTest extends TestCase {

  MockView mockView = new MockView();

  public void testApplication {
    Application a = new Application() {    <---
      protected View createView() {        <---
        return mockView;                   <--- whao, what is this?
      }                                    <---
    };                                     <---
    a.run();
    mockView.validate();
  }

  private class MockView extends View
  {
    boolean isDisplayed = false;

    public void display() {
      isDisplayed = true;
    }

    public void validate() {
      assertTrue(isDisplayed);
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The general concept being used there is [Anonymous Classes](http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/java-ent/jnut/ch03_12.htm)

What you have effectively done is to create a new sub-class of Application, overriding (or implementing) a method in sub-class. Since the sub-class is unnamed (anonymous) you cannot create any further instances of that class.

You can use this same technique to implement an interface, or to instantiate an abstract class, as long as you implement all necessary methods in your definition.

Comment: just curious, at what version of Java was this introduced?

Comment: I believe it was added in Java 1.1. It was definitely there when I started learning the language over 10 years ago :-)

Answer (score 4):

As others pointed out the code is creating mock objects for the purpose of testing. But it is also doing something called "Anonymous Inner Class".